# Searching for embedded XML-RPC server (with SSL/TLS)

Tags: c++, soap, xml-rpc, embeddedwebserver

I'm searching for xmlrpc libraries that can be embedded in a C++ application. [XmlRpc++ on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlrpcpp/) is a very neat solution but doesn't provide HTTPS support.

Other RPC-like solutions such as [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapmain.html) are not free for commercial use (or do I get that wrong, they mention [a MPL-like license](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soaplicense.html), too).

What about Apache's Axis/C++, can it be embedded somehow (I only found [an unanswered mailing list entry](http://osdir.com/ml/axis-c-dev-ws.apache.org/2009-07/msg00001.html))?

I'm thankful for any resources / library suggestions that

- can be embedded using C/C++
- support HTTPS (or SSL/TLS in general)
- may be used for commercial purposes

Answer (score 0):

There's [XMLRPC-EPI](http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net/) which to me seems to have a good license. Although it provides an server interface it isn't a HTTP/HTTPS server in itself. For that you need something else. But to me this seems like a good thing, as it keeps XMLRPC-EPI to its core function.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but I'm really searching for a solution with built-in HTTP(S) transport as that is supported by most client libraries.